# open files/directories in a directory owned by a user in Unix /Solaris/ C

Tags: c, unix, solaris

I need to get all files/directories owned by current user in a program. In fact i'm trying to read /proc filesystem in solaris(11) . Need to get output similar to ps -u but just the pids and needs to get it done from a program. What i tried is just did readdir and for each entry/dirname, try to read /pos/name/psinfo and if it fails skip else if it opens list the pid. Is there more efficient way of doing it ? I checked how ps -u is working through truss and  it only opened the /proc/pid/psinfo file for the user pids.Not sure how it figured out that this is current user pid .
I'm thinking popen("ps -u") is more efficient than what i'm doing and is there any better way to do this ? 
I'm trying to do this Solaris 11.

Here is sample code

```
     do
{
    errno = 0;
    pDirEnt= readdir(dptr);
    if(pDirEnt){
        sprintf(fileToOpen, "/proc/%s/psinfo", pDirEnt->d_name);
        sprintf(asfileToOpen, "/proc/%s/as", pDirEnt->d_name);
        count++;
        fd = open(fileToOpen, O_RDONLY);
        if(fd >= 0) {
            read(fd, &psInfo, sizeof(struct psinfo));
            close(fd);
            ..
            ..
        }
    } 

} while( haveMore );
```

Comment: You are asking simultaneously about 'file and directories owned by a user' and about 'ps -u' and `/proc`.  It isn't clear how/why you think these are connected.

Comment: Sorry I know i was not clear. since ps is implemented as /proc filesystem i had to link both of them. basically i need to emulate ps -u<currentuser> command in solaris and dont want to try to open everything under /proc and somehow figure out what are the current user pids

Comment: noted.will remove. thanks!

Comment: If "Not sure how it figured out that this is current user pid" is the key issue, then you should look into the `geteuid()` function.

Comment: @self: Why not set `errno`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  -  geteuid will get effective user for the current process. I need the owner of process for a pid

Comment: @chandrasekhar, there are only two possible definitions of the user who owns a *process*: either the identity it is operating under, or the identity the process that started it was operating under.  If you want (the process's idea of) the latter, then you can access it via `getuid()`.  If you want something else then you'll have to explain.

Comment: @JohnBollinger . sorry if i was not clear.  I need the getuid for a given process id .  something like     getuid(pid) . i need to get it for all the pids running to find out the list of pids created by current user.

Comment: `lsof` does what is asked - read its source code to see how it is done.

Comment: You can find the source code for the `ps` command [here](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ps/). Just have a look at how the `ps -u` is done in that source bundle. I believe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read `proc(4)`? That provides you with the documentation that you need for use of `/proc` on Solaris.

The `pfiles(1)` utility should help as well. However, if you want to see **all files open by a specific user** then you'll need to either run your program as that user, or run the program with suitably elevated privileges in order to read the process table.

I didn't find your problem description very clear, perhaps you could clarify exactly what it is that you are trying to achieve.